# GPS coordinates on Google maps with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, gps

I'm building a google map page that will act somewhat like a database for 4 or 5 gps devices around the country. the gps devices that i am using will have their own ip address within a router they will be connected to. to access the lattitude you would input EXAMPLE: **10.10.10.222/server/latitude.cgi** and that would access a file with just the text of the lattitude. My problem is that i don't know how to apply that into a google map javascript, does it just reads the text in the file automatically or i have to assign it to read the text? i can't test it for a few days so rather than get bogged down i figured id ask here.

The page describing the gps devices is ***[here](http://www.remotemonitoringsystems.ca/ngps/setup.php)***, along with how the information is pulled from it and how to call it.

here is my javascript with lattitude and longitude placeholders of (47,-100):

```
{
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(47, -100);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        icon: 'PointMarkerON.png',
        title: 'Site 1'

    })}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request gps url before calling Google Maps API.For example, if jquery is there :

```
$.get( "http://10.10.10.222/server/latitude.cgi", function( latitude ) {
    $.get( "http://10.10.10.222/server/longitude.cgi", function( longitude ) {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            icon: 'PointMarkerON.png',
            title: 'Site 1'
        });
    }); 
});
```